# Buffer allocation not in multiple of word size

Tags: c, memory-management, gdb, stack, buffer-overflow

I wrote a small program to understand the structure of stack.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void function(int a, int b, int c) {
    char buffer1[5];
    char buffer2[10];

    int *ret = buffer1 + 13;
    (*ret) += 8;
}

int main() {
    int x = 0;
    function(1,2,3);
    x = 1;
    printf("x = %d\n",x);
    return 0;
}
```

till now I have learnt that the stack follows below pattern

```
    ------------------
    |    arguments   |  High
    ------------------
    | return address |
    ------------------
    |       ebp      |
    ------------------
    |     buffer1    |
    ------------------
    |     buffer2    |  Low
    ------------------
```

I have also learnt that if we allocate 5 bytes of data, program allocates 8 (because it has to be a multiple of word size).

Dump of assembler code for function `function`:

```
0x08048414 <+0>:    push   %ebp
0x08048415 <+1>:    mov    %esp,%ebp
0x08048417 <+3>:    sub    $0x20,%esp
0x0804841a <+6>:    lea    -0x9(%ebp),%eax
0x0804841d <+9>:    add    $0xd,%eax
0x08048420 <+12>:   mov    %eax,-0x4(%ebp)
0x08048423 <+15>:   mov    -0x4(%ebp),%eax
0x08048426 <+18>:   mov    (%eax),%eax
0x08048428 <+20>:   lea    0x8(%eax),%edx
0x0804842b <+23>:   mov    -0x4(%ebp),%eax
0x0804842e <+26>:   mov    %edx,(%eax)
0x08048430 <+28>:   leave  
0x08048431 <+29>:   ret
```

End of assembler dump.

Now I run the program under gdb, I get,

```
(gdb) x/x $ebp
    0xbffff318: 0xbffff348
(gdb) x/x buffer1
    0xbffff30f: 0xfc73e461
(gdb) x/x buffer2
    0xbffff305: 0x0108049f
```

**Here's my doubt**, how can the difference between `buffer1` and `buffer2` be `10`, when everything is allocated in a multiple of wordsize.

Also how is there a difference of `9` between %ebp and `buffer1` ?

What exactly is happening here ?

**Note** :

- Consider stack grows from High to Low
- Wordsize = 4
- I'm using Intel processor, Ubuntu 12.04, 32bit and use

  `gcc -o stack -g -fno-stack-protector -O0 main.c`

to build.

Comment: The compiler is free to arrange the stack however it sees fit...

Comment: ... if even use it at all.

Comment: Character arrays don't need to be allocated on addresses that are a multiple of 4 (or even 2).  They can be aligned on odd boundaries.  On most machines, most other basic types will be allocated on boundaries that are a multiple of the basic size (2, 4, 8, 16 bytes), according to the size of the type.  Sometimes, the bigger types only need to be allocated on a multiple of 4 bytes.  You normally lose performance if you try to override the alignment requirements — by packing structures, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Here's my doubt, how can the difference between buffer1 and buffer2 be 0x10, when everything is allocated in a multiple of wordsize.

First, a correction: the difference between `buffer1` and `buffer2` is `10`, not `0x10` (which is `16`).

Second, *not everything* is allocated in multiple of words. The *total* frame size will be divisible by at least 8 to keep stack properly aligned for `doubles`, but *individual* local variables will only be aligned by whatever their alignment requirement is (which is `1` for characters and character buffers).

Comment: To anyone who has the same doubt, I recommend reading Jonathan's comment.